# Jenkins Service Account failing to pull from Git

Tags: jenkins

I am having some trouble that randomly started with Jenkins. All of our jobs have begin to fail and it looks like there is a credential issue with the service account we use to run our jobs. This randomly started. I have tried updating the version of Jenkins and the plugins, but there is no change. Here is the output we receive on any job that runs:

```
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials site git repo
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://site.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts/'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:886)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have also confirmed that the service account can login to our git repository with no issue and confirmed the security permissions on there for the account. I am completely clueless on how Jenkins operates and have inherited Jenkins from someone else, so I'm having a really tough time trying to figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I would also like to add that when I try to look at the job configurations, I receive this:

[image: Jenkins Job Failure]

Comment: What version of TLS is your server running?

Comment: Thanks for the response @pwaterz. Looking in the registry, I only see SSL 2.0 and it's disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what happened, but it looks like it seemed to fix itself. After updating Jenkins, it's plugins and Git on the master, the next morning we update the service account creds and that didn't work. Then we tried to use the alternative credentials found in Azure DevOps. Right after adding them in, we went to a job to change the credentials, but we did not receive the error from the picture above with the service account creds selected. We ran the job with the original creds and it ran without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the right credentials and if it has changed recently, don't forget to update it in Jenkins credential manager. I was facing a similar issue but when I updated the password - it resolved.